# how can i make my enemy slow down and wait before attack (like in dont starve/together)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okey, so Ill start with apologise for my code. Im learning. It may contain some dumb things, or some not working things. But I hope someones gonna help me. Lets start with my problem. So the problem is about my Enemy. My enemy is chasing me as it should, but when he aprouch me, then things start goes wrong. He is not dealing any damage, even after a minute. When he enters the attackRange, he is going blind into direction he had set on time he entered the attackRange.(he wont chase me as long as he leave the attackRange) and he isnt slowing down.

I want him to slow down when enter the attackRange(to 0.1f), wait before attack(like half a second) then attack(if the player is still in the attackRange(if not then he will just do his animation, but he wont deal any damage(Like in dont starve / together), then wait another half a second, and then I want him to get back to his previous speed.(I dont want to implement knockback and I guess it is trying force me to.
(Important is also that I dont want him to speed up when he leaves the attackRange, but I want him to speed up, after above things is done(slow down, wait, attack, wait, speed up)

Sorry if it is ununderstandable.

Im gonna post my code below(sorry it is 230 lines but I have no idea where did i messed a bit)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float chaseRange = 5f;
    public float attackRange = 1f;
    public float patrolSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float chaseSpeed = 0.75f;
    public float minIdleTime = 1f;
    public float maxIdleTime = 3f;
    public float minMoveTime = 1f;
    public float maxMoveTime = 3f;
    public eData enemyData;
    public float attackPrepareTime = 1f;
    public float attackCooldownTime = 2f;
    public int attackDamage = 9;

    private bool isChasing = false;
    private bool isPatrolling = true;
    private bool isIdle = false;
    private bool isAttacking = false;
    private bool isPreparingAttack = false;
    private bool isCooldown = false;
    private bool isReturning = false;
    private float idleTimer = 0f;
    private float idleTime = 0f;
    private float moveTimer = 0f;
    private float moveTime = 0f;
    private float attackPrepareTimer = 0f;
    private float attackCooldownTimer = 0f;
    private Vector2 patrolDirection;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Health enemyHealth;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<Health>();

        // Set enemy health from eData
        if (enemyHealth != null && enemyData != null)
        {
            enemyHealth.SetHealth(enemyData.hp, enemyData.hp);
        }

        idleTime = GetRandomIdleTime();
        moveTime = GetRandomMoveTime();
        patrolDirection = GetRandomDirection();
        moveDirection = GetRandomDirection();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (distanceToPlayer <= chaseRange && distanceToPlayer > attackRange)
        {
            isChasing = true;
            isPatrolling = false;
            ChasePlayer();
        }
        else if (isChasing && distanceToPlayer > chaseRange)
        {
            isChasing = false;
            isPatrolling = true;
            StopChasing();
        }

        if (isReturning)
        {
            ReturnToPlayer();
        }
        else if (isPatrolling)
        {
            Patrol();
        }

        if (isPreparingAttack)
        {
            attackPrepareTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (attackPrepareTimer >= attackPrepareTime)
            {
                isPreparingAttack = false;
                isAttacking = true;
                attackPrepareTimer = 0f;
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                Invoke("PerformAttack", 0.5f);
            }
        }

        if (isCooldown)
        {
            attackCooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (attackCooldownTimer >= attackCooldownTime)
            {
                isCooldown = false;
                attackCooldownTimer = 0f;
                if (!isReturning)
                {
                    rb.velocity = patrolDirection * patrolSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isAttacking)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

    private void ChasePlayer()
    {
        Vector2 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = direction * chaseSpeed;

        if (!isAttacking && !isPreparingAttack)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= attackRange)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                isPreparingAttack = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void StopChasing()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        isAttacking = false;
        isPreparingAttack = false;
        isCooldown = false;
        isReturning = true;
    }

    private void ReturnToPlayer()
    {
        Vector2 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = direction * chaseSpeed;

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= attackRange)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            isReturning = false; 
            isPreparingAttack = true;
        }
    }

    private void Patrol()
    {
        if (isIdle)
        {
            idleTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (idleTimer >= idleTime)
            {
                isIdle = false;
                moveTimer = 0f;
                moveTime = GetRandomMoveTime();
                moveDirection = GetRandomDirection();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (moveTimer >= moveTime)
            {
                isIdle = true;
                idleTimer = 0f;
                idleTime = GetRandomIdleTime();
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = moveDirection * patrolSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    private float GetRandomIdleTime()
    {
        return Random.Range(minIdleTime, maxIdleTime);
    }

    private float GetRandomMoveTime()
    {
        return Random.Range(minMoveTime, maxMoveTime);
    }

    private Vector2 GetRandomDirection()
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        float randomY = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        return new Vector2(randomX, randomY).normalized;
    }

    private void PerformAttack()
    {
        if (isAttacking)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= attackRange)
            {
                AttackPlayer();
            }

            isAttacking = false;
            isCooldown = true;
            Invoke("FinishAttack", 0.5f);
        }
    }

    private void FinishAttack()
    {
        isCooldown = false;
        if (!isReturning)
        {
            rb.velocity = chaseSpeed * (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
        }
    }

    private void AttackPlayer()
    {
        Health playerHealth = player.GetComponent<Health>();
        if (playerHealth != null)
        {
            playerHealth.Damage(attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set the attack cool down to max on getting to the player?

Comment: unfortunately nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You have too many boolean fields. The code is very difficult to understand and find errors.

Divide the logic into several parts. For example, the logic of movement and attack can be separated. You can separate them into different classes. You can also separate the logic of pursuit and patrol move.

I wrote an example code, of course it is far from ideal, but it is much clearer and it will be much easier to find errors in it.

Base enemy class:

```
using Players;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Enemies
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(EnemyChase))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(EnemyPatrol))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(EnemyAttack))]
    public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Player player;
        [SerializeField] private float damage = 1f;
            
        private EnemyPatrol patrol;
        private EnemyChase chase;
        private EnemyAttack attack;
        
        private IEnemyMoveStage currentMover;

        private void Awake()
        {   
            patrol = GetComponent<EnemyPatrol>();
            chase = GetComponent<EnemyChase>();
            attack = GetComponent<EnemyAttack>();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            chase.SetChaseTarget(player.transform);
            ChangeMover(patrol);
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            attack.OnAttack += HitPlayer;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (attack.IsAttack)
            {
                return;
            }
            var distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);
            if (distance < chase.Range)
            {
                if (distance < attack.Range)
                {
                    attack.Attack(player.transform);
                    return;
                }
                ChangeMover(chase);
                return;
            }
            ChangeMover(patrol);
        }

        private void ChangeMover(IEnemyMoveStage next)
        {
            if (currentMover == null)
            {
                currentMover = next;
                currentMover.Run();
                return;
            }
            if (currentMover == next)
            {
                return;
            }
            currentMover.Stop();
            currentMover = next;
            currentMover.Run();
        }

        private void HitPlayer()
        {
            player.Hit(damage);
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            attack.OnAttack -= HitPlayer;
        }
    }
}
```

2 mover classes:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Enemies
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class EnemyChase: MonoBehaviour, IEnemyMoveStage
    {
        [SerializeField] private float speed = 0.75f;
        [SerializeField] private float range = 5f;

        public float Range => range;
        
        private Rigidbody rigidBody;
        private Transform target;
        private bool isChasing;

        private void Awake()
        {
            rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

        public void SetChaseTarget(Transform chaseTarget)
        {
            target = chaseTarget;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!isChasing)
            {
                return;
            }
            Vector2 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
            rigidBody.velocity = direction * speed;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            isChasing = true;
        }
        
        public void Stop()
        {
            isChasing = false;
        }
    }
}



using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace Enemies
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour, IEnemyMoveStage
    {
        [SerializeField] private EnemyPatrolStep[] patrolSteps =
        {
            new(0.5f, 1f, 3f),
            new(0f, 1f, 3f),
        };

        private Rigidbody rigidBody;

        private float maxTime;
        private float timer;
        private float speed;
        private Vector3 direction;
        private int patrolStep;
        private bool isPatrol;
        
        private void Awake()
        {
            rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            
            patrolStep = -1;
            GoToNextStep();
        }
        
        private void Update()
        {
            if (!isPatrol)
            {
                return;
            }
            
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= maxTime)
            {
                timer = 0;
                GoToNextStep();
                return;
            }
            
            rigidBody.velocity = direction * speed;
        }

        private void GoToNextStep()
        {
            if (++patrolStep >= patrolSteps.Length)
            {
                patrolStep = 0;
            }

            var step = patrolSteps[patrolStep];
            maxTime = GetRandomTime(step.MinTime, step.MaxTime);
            direction = GetRandomDirection();
            speed = step.Speed;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            isPatrol = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            isPatrol = false;
        }
        
        #region Random
        // ToDo: move in separate config class
        private float GetRandomTime(float min, float max)
        {
            return Random.Range(min, max);
        }

        private Vector2 GetRandomDirection()
        {
            var randomX = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
            var randomY = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
            return new Vector2(randomX, randomY).normalized;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I created simple interface for them:

```
namespace Enemies
{
    public interface IEnemyMoveStage
    {
        public void Run();
        public void Stop();
    }
}
```

and created a settings class - just for convenience:

```
using System;

namespace Enemies
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EnemyPatrolStep
    {
        public float Speed;
        public float MinTime;
        public float MaxTime;

        public EnemyPatrolStep(float speed, float minTime, float maxTime)
        {
            Speed = speed;
            MinTime = minTime;
            MaxTime = maxTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Attack class (It's not quite complete because I couldn't understand the full logic of emeny attacks.)

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Enemies
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public event Action OnAttack;
        
        [SerializeField] private float range = 5f;
        [SerializeField] private float attackDelay = 0.5f;
        
        public float Range => range;
        public bool IsAttack => isAttack;
        
        private Rigidbody rigidBody;

        private Transform target; 
        private bool isAttack;
        
        private float maxTime;
        private float timer;
        private float speed;
        
        private void Awake()
        {
            rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
        
        public void Attack(Transform attackTarget)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            target = attackTarget;
            isAttack = true;
            timer = 0;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!isAttack)
            {
                return;
            }

            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer < attackDelay)
            {
                return;
            }

            Attack();
        }

        private void Attack()
        {
            if (target != null && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < range)
            {
                OnAttack?.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Enemy missed");
            }
            isAttack = false;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. For the movement of bots, it is better to use ready libraries and tools. Unity.AI, for example